# here maps how to disable zooming on double click

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I'm using [HERE JavaScript API](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis) and I'd like to disable zooming on map double click.
Anybody know how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the "*Enabling and Disabling Double Click Zoom*" example on the [HERE Maps Community pages](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#enabling-and-disabling-double-click-zoom).

Assuming you already have a map with the standard [nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/#topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior.html) component, you  will get a `nokia.maps.map.DoubleClick` component loaded by default.

To **enable** DoubleClick (if you haven't loaded behavior)

```
map.addComponent(new nokia.maps.map.component.zoom.DoubleClick());
```

To **disable** DoubleClick

```
 map.removeComponent(map.getComponentById("zoom.DoubleClick"));
```

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish the same thing in version 3 of the API

```
var map = new H.Map(...);
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// responsible for disabling the double tap (click) to zoom
behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.DBLTAPZOOM);
```

Answer (score 0):

`stopPropagation()` is what you are looking for:

```
map.addListener( "dblclick", function( evt ) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   // stuff you want to do on double click on map
});
```